# Creating SFML window triggers breakpoint

Tags: c, window, sfml

I am trying to open a SFML window in my program. The program actually works (tested it at school). Now back at my own computer I often (not always) get the error "Game_of_Life.exe triggered a breakpoint". That especially happens whenever I try to add code. But even if I delete the code just added, it won't start working properly again.

Here's the code:

```
world_1.gen = Start_Gen(config.world_size); 
copy_gen = (int *)calloc(config.world_size * config.world_size, sizeof(int));
world_1.recs = Create_Empty_Recs(config.world_size);    

//window parameter
mode.height = config.window_size;
mode.width = config.window_size;
mode.bitsPerPixel = 32;

world_1.window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode, world_1.name, sfResize | sfClose, NULL);
```

The error occurs in the last line.
Can anybody point me to the flaw? It feels like my IDE Visual Studio 2012 is just acting randomly.

Thanks in advance

Jonas

Comment: Did you copy the SFML libraries next to the compiled executable?

Comment: Yes I did. I don't think there is any problem with including SFML into the project. I discovered that as I deleted some extra Code that isn't necessary to the program at the moment, it compiles just fine.

So that confuses me. How can a program run, until you define some additional variables that you just don't use. In my opinion it shouldn't affect the program at all...

Comment: A professional programmer told me that the additional code possibly messes up the pointer to world_1.window somewhere... Finding the flaw is probably way beyond my C skills